# Node JS/ Angular

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

I have installed Node JS and then imported an existing work project in Visual Studio Code.  After that I ran `npm install` in the project folder, then run `npm start` and the app comes up fine.  However, if I run an `ng` command I get an error telling me "ng is not valid command", even though the Angular CLI is in the modules folder.

I tried manually installing Angular CLI globally and set system path to point to the npm folder, and then the `ng` command works fine.  What I don't understand is why do I need to install CLI globally if I just want to run that command within the project where the module is already present?

Comment: You can also add your local installation to your PATH. But why would someone do that???

Comment: I dont want to do that...but what i am understand is why is ng not recognized when i see angular cli in the modules folder

Comment: Because your modules folder is not your OS' path

Comment: To run a command for a locally installed npm module, use `npx`. [npx](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/162869356040/introducing-npx-an-npm-package-runner)

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule then you will need to install globally any commands you wish to use (without NPX). This isn't really a restriction of NPM so much as it is a fundamental way in which command line programs work. The OS will only look in fixed predefined locations set in PATH. This applies to any Node based tool such as `grunt` or `ng` or whatever.

(While some systems do look for executables relative to the current working directory, or can be configured to, it's generally not a good or reliable method and NPM doesn't rely on this behaviour).

For something like the Angular CLI then installing it globally should be fine and is what many people will do. As a general rule if it is a command you want to run, rather than a dependency for a project, you can consider installing it globally. You'll notice that on the [Angular CLI page](https://cli.angular.io/) the example does exactly that.

In many cases however you might want to run a command from a local project. Perhaps for a build script or something else where you want to keep it isolated. In that case you instead prefix your command with [npx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) which will look inside the local project for commands.